# Error LNK2019 unresolved external symbol main referenced in function "int __cdecl __scrt_common_main_seh(void)" (?__scrt_common_main_seh@@YAHXZ)

Tags: c++, visual-studio, user-interface, linker, entry-point

I am trying to create a new **GUI project** in visual studio community ***2017*** using the following video : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QCnyqMWPkQk

When I run the program for the first time I got the entry point error. I solved it by setting the sub system in the linker to Console (/SUBSYSTEM:CONSOLE).

However, after running the code again I got that error "LNK2019". Is the problem related to the entry point as well?

what should I do to solve this error ?

Comment: I got this particular error when my executable did not have a `main()` function defined.

Answer (score -6, accepted):

I solved my problem by the following:

1) closing the project and restarting the PC

2) Creating a new project and following this thread
http://www.bogotobogo.com/cplusplus/application_visual_studio_2013.php

Answer (score -4):

Go to `Project Properties > Linker > Input`

At the field `Ignore Specific Default Libraries` Add:
`msvcrt.lib`

and you're done with it.